# Header CSS not applying upto the top of page

Tags: html, css

```css
#header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is a page used by admins to change the content.</title>
</head>

<link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="../includes/style.css">

<div id="header">
  <h2> <strong> Admin page. </strong> </h2>
</div>

<body style="background-color:cyan;">
  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentcolumn">
      <div class="innertext">

        <h3>
          <p> Insert your credentials here: Note that if you log in, you will be redirected to the main page.</p>
        </h3>

        <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
      </div>

      <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
      <strong> <small style="color:aa0000;">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </small></strong>
      <?php } ?>

    </div>
  </div>


  <br> <br> <br> <br>
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="../index.php"> Main Page </a>
  </div>

</body>

</hmtl>
```

I have a small site, and for some reason, this appears:
[Page with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrPjN.png). The issue is that a cyan line appears above the black header, when it shouldn't appear.

And the CSS code for the header, where the issue appears:

```css
#header {
    background: black;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Now, what I've tried (all of these failed):
a) Change the `header` id on the first `div` to `footer`, which has this code:

```css
#footer {
    clear:left;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-align:center;
}
```

b) Change the code of `header` to be the same as `footer`.

The only thing that works, although I don't know why, is if I write something **before** the `<h2>` tag of the first `div`, like so:

```html
<div id="header">
    a<h2> <strong> Admin page. </strong> </h2>
</div>
```

Which results to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ED4.png)

I honestly don't know why the issue is present only here, because I have other sites where this issue isn't present. Could someone please explain?

Also, this HTML code is under some PHP code, which is essentially a login form.

Comment: You talk about *"the issue"* but never actually explain what it is. My guess goes to the header not aligning at the top of the page?

Comment: The issue is the blue line that appears at the top of the screen, above the black header.

Comment: This happens because the `h2` has `margin` moving the header downwards. Try removing the margin on the `h2`

Comment: please consider to edit the title to something meaningful

Comment: In dev tools in a browser, you should analyze your margins and paddings. If you are new to CSS, I recommend using a CSS framework such as [bulma](https://bulma.io/) to help you quickly get a design and see how they set margins and paddings.

Comment: Also, your html doesn't have the right structure. See the first example here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp . After <head> you need to open a <body>, inside body is where all your content goes.

Comment: I'm sorry, it must be too early in the morning... I can't seem to find any `margin` in `h2`. Do you mean that I have a CSS rule for `h2`? Because, if so, the only rule I have is on `h3`, and that's just a `color` and `font-style` rule. If I didn't catch your answer, could you please simplify it for me?

Comment: Move your header into body and make body 100% width and height. body is the place where all your content should be. I follow that rule.

Comment: The browser has default styling for each element, not just the rules you define. So the `margin` on the `h2` is just the browsers default style. As solution you can add the following CSS rule: `#header h2 { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

The collapsing margin is cousing the problem. Remove top margin on h2 or add a padding or a boarder (1px) to a header element

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing.

> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of one or more of its descendant blocks; or no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of one or more of its descendant blocks, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

[More on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

Add This Line at the top of your CSS file:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Working Code:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#header {
    background: black;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    height:10%;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer {
    clear:left;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a page used by admins to change the content.</title>
    <link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="../includes/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:cyan;">
  <div id="header">
    <h2> <strong> Admin page. </strong> </h2>
  </div>

  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentcolumn">
      <div class="innertext">
                <h3>
                    Insert your credentials here: Note that if you log in, you will be redirected to the main page.
                </h3>

                <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

                </form>
            </div>

            <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
            <strong> <small style="color:aa0000;">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </small></strong>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>


    <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="../index.php"> Main Page </a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And for god's Sake please learn some basics of HTML